# I can't log in Chromium (I was a Chrome user before this, so should make another account or something)?

Tags: google-chrome, login, chromium

I click on profile icon at the top right-hand in chromium and enter my user and pass and click on "log in" button but the frame disappears and I'm not logged in yet, what should I do?

Comment: Clear your Cookies first. and still if it's showing then will give you another solution. :)

Comment: still I can't log in

Comment: I am providing you some steps please try it: Step 1) Click on the menu button. Step 2) Select "setting" on menu. Step 3) Select "Advanced Sync Everything" under "Sing In" group. Step 4) Select "Ok" on the dialog, and make sure the Combo box is on the value as "Sync everything". After that try. If still not working then will try something else,.. :)

Comment: Okay.. No problem...

Answer (score 34):

As of 15th of March 2021, Google removed several features from all third-party Chromium-based browsers (also Chromium itself) including synchronization. Users need to either install and use Google Chrome or use alternatives (other web browsers/extensions that provide such a service).

> During a recent audit, we discovered that some third-party Chromium based browsers were able to integrate Google features, such as Chrome sync and Click to Call, that are only intended for Google’s use. This meant that a small fraction of users could sign into their Google Account and store their personal Chrome sync data, such as bookmarks, not just with Google Chrome, but also with some third-party Chromium based browsers. We are limiting access to our private Chrome APIs starting on March 15, 2021.
>
> For users who accessed Google features (like Chrome sync) through a third-party Chromium based browser, their data will continue to be available in their Google Account, and data that they have stored locally will continue to be available locally. As always, users can view and manage their data on the My Google Activity page. They can also download their data from the Google Takeout page, and/or delete it here.
>
> Guidance for vendors of third-party Chromium based products is available on the Chromium wiki.

Source: [Limiting Private API availability in Chromium](https://blog.chromium.org/2021/01/limiting-private-api-availability-in.html)

Comment: The evil corporation strikes again...

Comment: Yay it's enforcement to totally not using google account, I wont letting all my data goes to 1 **giant** company :).

Answer (score 4):

If you are still facing this problem then I recommend you to just follow these 3 steps that I followed for mine:

Go to chromium settings, select *You and Google* then *Sync and Google Services*, and then TURN-OFF **Allow Chromium sign-in** and then you are done.

Comment: the menu already reorganized right now

Comment: How would this help with logging in?

Answer (score 3):

"Chrome Sync API" requires API keys.

See [The Chromium Projects - For Developers‎ > ‎How-Tos‎ > ‎
API Keys](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys).

Comment: I have the same problem as the original poster - how does this answer relate to me as a mere Chromium user? The API keys seem to be all about writing Chrome extensions... I'm confused :(

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend @L_K answer: after creating API key according to http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys, you will need to add enviroment variables in any way, for example:

**For Windows users** run this commands in `cmd.exe`:

`setx GOOGLE_API_KEY your_key_goes_here`

`setx GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID your_client_id_goes_here`

`setx GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET your_client_secret_goes_here`

**For Mac OS X / Linux**: Plop these in your `~/.profile file`:

`export GOOGLE_API_KEY="your_key_goes_here"`

`export GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID="your_client_id_goes_here"`

`export GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET="your_client_secret_goes_here"`

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I did this in Linux Mint, but how does this help solve this problem? I still can't enable Chromium Sync. It never logs me in.